# Where does '~' expand to when mounted in docker with windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a docker container I wrote that sets up AWS profiles for me. In Linux it works great, on WSL it partially works.

When I run the container I am mounting the `~/.aws` directory, checking if the profiles exist and if they don't exist I create them. If they do exist I don't do anything.

In Linux I can run this container and then continue to use aws-cli with no problems.
In Windows subsystem for Linux - when I run the container the first time around, it will create the profiles for me. If I choose to run the container again it sees that the profiles already exist so it does nothing. This tells me the file exists *somewhere* but I cant use aws-cli because the file doesn't exist at `~/.aws`.

So my question is where is `~/.aws` in WSL when mounted to a docker container? I've attempted to do a find on the entire filesystem in WSL and that returns nothing. I've also tried changing the mount path to `/root/.aws` and I run into the same conditions.

EDIT:

I still don't know the answer to my question above. But if anyone comes across this question I did find a work around.

I've updated Docker Desktop to allow mounting the entire `c:/` drive. Then I just changed my docker run command to mount `c:/.aws` instead of `~/.aws`, so my command looks like `-v c:/.aws:/root/.aws`. After that I added this environment variable in WSL `export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE="/mnt/c/.aws/credentials"` and now aws cli picks up on my profile changes.

Comment: Before I can attempt to answer this could you please state which version of WSL you are using, 1 or 2? and what version of docker you are using, i assume you are using docker for windows as the engine? Finally do you have the docker CLI installed inside WSL?

Comment: @Damo Im using WSL1, Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 (engine version 19.03.8). Yes it is docker for windows as the engine and I do have docker cli installed in WSL.

Comment: Can you post the docker run command that you are running that mounts the ~/.aws directory please

Comment: @Damo `docker run -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws awsprofileprocessor:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that in your setup the docker engine (docker for windows) is installed on windows, it is inside the windows environment that the docker command is 'launched'. So when you say use ~/.aws it looks in the windows file system for this location.

In windows ~ is a valid directory name (try mkdir ~ from a cmd prompt) so when you say map ~/.aws I'm unsure what actually gets created. maybe try searching your c drive for a folder called ~. There is no ~ shortcut in windows for the home folder, and if there was which home would it be? the home of the logged in windows user? or the home inside WSL?

To make this work in WSL you need to pass ~/.aws to wslpath like this:

```
➜  echo $(wslpath ~/.aws)
/mnt/c/home/damo/.aws
```

But this location is the path according to WSL not windows you need to do it twice with the -w flag the second time

```
➜  echo $(wslpath -w $(wslpath ~/.aws))
C:\home\damo\.aws
```

which would make your final docker command look like this:

```
docker run -it -v  $(wslpath -w $(wslpath ~/.aws)):/root/.aws awsprofileprocessor:latest
```

With this you will now be telling docker for windows the windows path to put the mount

Please let me know if this works for you, I'm interested in how it turns out.

Comment: This was it, I was able to find a directory called `~` on the windows side. I didn't end up using `wslpath` but instead just hard coded it to `c:/.aws` and then utilized the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable in WSL to point to that path. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The shell always expands `~` to the value of the `HOME` environment variable.  If that environment variable is not set, then it expands to nothing.  If you want to find where `~/.aws` is located, then you can write something like `echo ~/.aws` and the shell will expand it for you.

The only exception is that `~user` expands to the home directory of the user `user`; the `HOME` environment variable is not consulted there.

Comment: This is not the case here. I think since WSL docker is using docker desktop for windows its somewhere on my C drive. Even if I hardcode `/root/.aws` as the mount point it still does not actually show up at `/root/.aws`.